# MongoDB strict evaluation of condition

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I am wondering if I am doing something wrong, or MongoDB really strictly evaluates both branches of `$cond` operator. See following example:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[  
   {  
      "$project":{ 
         "condition":{  
            "$cond":{  
               "if": true,
               "then":{  
                  "$literal":"NaN"
               },
               "else":{  
                  "$divide":[  
                     {  
                        "$literal":0.0
                     },
                     {  
                        "$literal":0.0
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
]

)
```

This aggregation should, in my opinion, return `NaN`(for every matching document), but instead, I get division by zero error. Why is the `else` branch of the condition evaluated, when clearly the `then` condition is going to be returned?

This only happens if I divide two `$literal`s, if one of the operands is a column reference, even if the column evaluates to `0`, it works as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all there is no need to use `$literal`.

```
db.collection.aggregate(
[  
   {  
      "$project":{ 
         "condition":{  
            "$cond":{  
               "if": true,
               "then": "NaN",
               "else":{ "$divide":[ 0.0, 0.0] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
]

)
```

does exactly the same thing.

Now about the error. `"$divide":[ 0.0, 0.0]` has 2 constants and is calculated before running the query on the client, which seems to be fair optimisation.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that's all I needed to know. I don't like it, but at least I know there is nothing I can do about it.